# Compilied queries with return anonymous type

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

Is it possible to return anonymous type from compiledQuery in linq to entity framework. If yes can you please post solution sample.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3782e05c-8a21-462c-950d-3410072c185e